# UTF8 changed to Latina 1 - Umlauts are not considered

Tags: sql, utf-8, character-encoding, mariadb, sql-update

I am currently updating a table using the UPDATE command, whereby a text section is also read from another table using a substring. The command works fine so far. The only problem are the umlauts, which are not taken into account during the update. As I found out, for some reason the substring is rewritten into the format latina1, although the corresponding column of the table (action) has utf8 preset. Enclosed is the code for updating.
SQL:

```
update vms_vertrag_datei d
inner join vms_vertrag_verlauf v ON d.vertrag = v.vertrag
SET  d.nutzer = v.nutzer, d.uploaddatum= v.timestamp
WHERE d.filename in (SELECT DISTINCT SUBSTRING(v.aktion,LOCATE('"',v.aktion)+1,(((LENGTH(v.aktion))-LOCATE('"', REVERSE(v.aktion))-1)-LOCATE('"',v.aktion)))FROM vms_vertrag_verlauf v)
AND v.aktion like 'Datei%hinzugefügt';
```

Does anyone know how I can now also consider text with umlauts? Am just after longer online research something at despair.

Comment: Can you create a [DBFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.6) which reproduces this problem?

Comment: I am already trying ... Can you tell me if table names with variables can be shortened there as well? My current status is here. However, the update command does not work there: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.4&fiddle=2dfd92a7efac7d031d72bf5700277148

Comment: The `filename in....` piece seems incorrect, see: [DBFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.4&fiddle=bd0c1ec3b2a77ba3bd2534cfe4d0fd75)

Comment: Thank you so much, you really made my day today. If I had known that I could have had the substring so short and that everything would work, I could have saved myself a lot of frustration and time. You are my hero of the day!